# Take x,y coordinates from a nested dictionary and print to a console, python game

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

So I'm making a game where I use a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'game_1': {player_1 :{'x': [(1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0)], player_2:{'o': [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 2)]}}, 'game_2': {player_1:{'x': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], player_2{'o': [(0, 1), (1, 1)]}}}
```

I want to take the first value of `x` and use it as coordinates on a 3x3 board to print the letter `x` in that x, y coordinate. Then go to the first value of `o` and print an `o` to that x, y coordinate and continue going back and forth between the `x` and `o` until that game is finished.

My code looks like this:

```py
def game_board(dict):

    board = [" " for x in range(10)]

    print("   |   |   ")
    print(" " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + " | " + board[3] + "  ")
    print("   |   |")
    print("---|---|---")
    print("   |   |")
    print(" " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + " | " + board[6] + "  ")
    print("   |   |")
    print("---|---|---")
    print("   |   |")
    print(" " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + " | " + board[9] + "  ")
    print("   |   |   ")

    for x in file:
        x_x_y = []
        if x in file:
            coordinates_x = x[0:1]
            coordinates_y = x[0:2]
            x_x_y.append(coordinates_x)
            x_x_y.append(coordinates_y)
            print(x_x_y)
    for o in file:
        o_x_y = []
        if o in file:
            coordinates_x = o[1:1]
            coordinates_y = o[1:2]
            o_x_y.append(coordinates_x)
            o_x_y.append(coordinates_y)
```

I'm not sure what to do from this point or even if I'm on the right track. Thank-you

Comment: One thing I notice right away is that you player 1 is always X and player 2 is always O, thus there is no need to complexify the dictionnary by saying Player 1 > X > coordinates. The intermediate X is redundant with the player 1 information. What is the problem you are facing with your current code?

Comment: player_1 and player_2 are variables that change with each game, another later part of the challenge I will have to face is keeping track of wins and looses for each individual player. The error message I get is :
 line 56, in game_board
    for x in dict:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Well now that I look at it again, what is `file`? It isn't define in the scope of the function. Then, the combination `for x in file: if x in file:` doesn't make sense. It is the same as doing `for i in [1, 2]: if i in [1, 2]: do something`. On the first iteration, `i=1`, and obviously `i` is in the list containing 1 and 2. Same thing for the second iteration where `i=2`.

Comment: I voted to close the post as it is unclear and need more information. One more point I noticed, you initialize the board with a list of 10 empty strings. Yet, as it's tic-tac-toe and as your print suggest, there are only 9 empty spots. I would also highly suggest you have a look at classes. You might want to define a class for the board and a class for the players.